# What crypto scheme should I use on embedded m2m system with assymetric uplink/downlink bandwidth?

Tags: public-key, embedded

I am working on implementing info security into custom m2m radiolink communication system, which has some restrictions: MCU based endpoint can transmit to gateway with packets max 16 bytes long, and the cyphertext **should not exceed that**, gateway can also downlink to endpoint with packets up to 64 bytes. Minimization of transmitted overhead is a priority (battery preserve). I need a public key encryption scheme, which can be squeezed into such small payload footprint. Usual RSA based algorithms seem to use too long chunks and not an option. I can afford to send long packets ocasionally (i.e. for session key synchronisation once in a while). The endpoint may get into attackers hands, so no secrets should be stored there. The air traffic is considered fully sniffable, gateway may be considered physically safe. What scheme can I use, which meets these demands?

Comment: 128 bit (16-byte) is too short for an asymmetric ciphertext. You'll have to use asymmetric encryption (or key agreement) split over a few packets to establish a symmetric key.

Comment: Yep, I understand that. What implementation of key agreement can I use? The MCU has aes engine, so I guess I will use that for encryption and only regulary update the keys over assymetric

Comment: http://robotics.stanford.edu/~xb/asiacrypt07/index.html $\;$ https://cseweb.ucsd.edu/~mihir/papers/fspkc.pdf $\hspace{.7 in}$

Comment: You should define your objectives better. You mention asymmetric encryption, what about authentication of the origin of messages? Can there be two-way communication with the intended final receiver of the encrypted message? Do you want forward secrecy? Do you need some level of resistance to traffic analysis? What can adversaries attempt (in particular, on what are they in a position to hook a jtag probe or equivalent? On other devices, can they measure the device's power consumption? Exploit EM emission beyond the radio link?) What's the legal context?